# How do I get a winning picture in a slide puzzle?

Tags: javascript, p5.js, puzzle

I make a slide puzzle game. When the puzzle is solved "won" should be displayed and the timer should stop.

I hope you can help me. Thanks.

Here is a link to the web editor for my puzzle [link](https://editor.p5js.org/Nightdragon22/sketches/PP9MnmVJG)

Here is the part of the code but it doesn´t work:

```
function draw() {
  if (isSolved()) {
    console.log('SOLVED');
    timerValue = 0;
    text('Won', width/2, height/2);
  }   
}

function isSolved() {
  for (let i = 0; i < plate.length - 1; i++) {
    if (plate[i] !== tiles[i].index) {
      return false;
    }
  }
return true;
}
```

Comment: Please give us a reproduceable example! We can't actually begin to solve your problem without assuming a couple of things. It would be helpful to have the array `plate` and the array `tiles` in your question. Once I get those things (or just a link to the web editor) I'll work on a fix.

Comment: @KoderM here is a link to the web editor for the puzzle [link](https://editor.p5js.org/Nightdragon22/sketches/PP9MnmVJG)

Comment: For your "gameover" statment on line 84. Use `noLoop()` instead of reassigning the `draw` function. But I think the answer is that you aren't swapping the places of the `plate` array along with the `tile` array.

Comment: @KoderM Thank you. I have added `noLoop( )` to my code.

Answer (score -1):

P5JS is saying that `createImage() was expecting Integer for the second parameter, received number instead.` This can be solved by changing `let img = createImage(w, h);` tp `let img = createImage(int(w), int(h));`.

I'm not entirely sure if this helps, because I don't know how your puzzle works (how it's solved) so please tell me if this doesn't work and I'll investigate further.

Comment: This would be better as a comment. It's not a full, tested answer.

Comment: @Voxel Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately this didn´t work. I have now found another solution to my problem.